# Boot delay errors?

Tags: linux, ext4

I continuously get these messages upon boot:

```
[   17.806441] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null) 

[  157.196550]
postgres (1297): /proc/1297/oom_adj is deprecated, please use
/proc/1297/oom_score_adj instead.
```

As you can see from the time differences, this is a massive delay! How would I fix this? This happens on every single version of my builds (across 30-40 hard drives), so i do not believe its a hard drive issue, though they are all direct copies of one master.

Is this the boot delay? How do i fix it? Any insight would be helpful.

My superior believes there is not enough proof to say this is the reason the boot up is taking so long. If its not this (dmesg print out), then what could it be?

Notes:

Version = Linaro 13.08 (GNU/Linux 3.15.0+ armv7l)

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong problem. The EXT4 is corrupted, but you should check why this is the case at every boot. The first line is a good start: it is an error before mounting the filesystems and possibly a similar script fail at shutdown.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi so you propose i look at the plymouth message first? I really dont know how to approach this

Comment: start in rescue or single-user mode, and at console do `fsck -t ext4 -A -a -C` to automatically check and repair all ext4 filesystems with progress counter. Then reboot. See the same delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was found, by using the application bootchart A graph was formed of all the start up processes, found within it was a large 2 minute sleep process!

This 2 minute sleep was found within /etc/init/failsafe.conf <- this delay is meant to echo out to the terminal, though it did not. by modifying the script i managed to get my system booted in 23 seconds. Though other issues come with this, but not anything i cannot fix easily / hack together.

The other issues was the DHCP server would not come up when broadcasting the SSID, it would just fail.

I threw together a script which i put with @reboot into crontab -e which looped through checking if the service was running, if it wasnt running it would start it and keep trying untill started.

Comment: If you don't mind, and for the others that come here with the issue, can you expand your answer with the other associated problems and their solution(s)?

Comment: sure @Azulflame

Comment: what or where is this application "bootchart"?

Comment: @Otheus I apt-get installed it... it will then generate charts in /var/log/bootchart as pngs make sure you research it and have everything installed (bootchart, pycharts etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

The postgresql message can be ignored for now, but if you want to fix it, you should change Postgresql's init script. Look in your init script (`/etc/init.d/postgresql`) for something like:

```
    test x"$PG_OOM_ADJ" != x && echo "$PG_OOM_ADJ" > /proc/self/oom_adj
```

and change it to

```
    test x"$PG_OOM_ADJ" != x && echo "$PG_OOM_ADJ" > /proc/self/oom_adj_score
```

It's also possible you don't need postgresql to run, so you can try disabling it.